Custom (external) reference voltage for ADC: is there a lower limit?
I'm reading an analogue oxygen sensor (SGX-4OX) with a Nano Every (ATmega4809-based). We're seeing up to about 60mV* in ambient air (it will reduce as we purge with nitrogen), and the ADC is 10-bit.  We don't need very high precision but we'd like to make the best of what we've got without amplifying the sensor output.
The documentation on analogReference doesn't mention the Nano Every yet, but setting it to "Internal" we seem to saturate at around 600mV.  From other models I'd expect it to be 1V or 1.1V.  So we're using about 10% of our dynamic range, and get ~0.2%O2 resolution.  This is probably adequate, but I always try to fill my inputs' dynamic range a bit more, and relies on the internal reference being lower than expected.
Could I, either with a voltage reference IC, a voltage divider, or a combination of the 2, set a lower reference voltage - perhaps 100mV.

* The sensor is a current source, so choosing the sense resistor allows us to adjust the sensitivity.  We don't want to go too far from the manufacturer's recommended value (linearity and lifetime, which is finite anyway), and even to get 60mV is pushing it.

There are dev boards using the same sensor.  We may end up using one but want to try and make progress with what we've got.

Be mindful of the precision of the resistors used for the voltage divider. Any tolerance variation can affect the readings.

@liaifat85 indeed.  I'll probably measure V_ref rather than calculating it, and anyway it will come out in my calibration (at ambient and 0% O2, maybe an intermediate value as we have commercial O2 monitors that are far too big for our experiment).  By using the same type of resistor the ratio should at least stay constant with temperature.  We may well end up with precision greater than our accuracy, but can still spot trends from that, which will be useful

The Nano Every is based on the ATmega4809, the datasheet for which can be found at https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/atmega4809
According to table 32-25 on p478 of version C of the datasheet, the reference voltage should be no lower than 1.1V if an external reference is used (VREF when REFSEL = External reference).
There is an internal 0.55V reference that allows operation down to 0.55V, which the lowest setting of the internal reference. Section 18 of the datasheet talks more about the internal reference.
So to answer the title question: Yes there is a limit and it is 1.1V for an external reference.

That's a much longer datasheet than the one I found (I don't have the link here but do in work).  It explains the unexpectedly low maximum value I found setting analogReferenceto internal

For Microchip's 8-bit parts, that's about the size of datasheet I would expect to see, although some of the 16-bit or 32-bit parts have separate per-peripheral datasheets.

I agree, but I think there's a short form as well. Or I suppose something could have been going on with the in-browser PDF viewer failing to download or search everything

... it must have been the latter.  I'd seen §18 but my search for VREF wrapped round before the table loaded (I still had it open)
